# convert criteria object to list in mysql db

Tags: mysql, hibernate

When i am using oracle database the following query is executed perfectly in hibernate.But i am trying to using mysql db means it doesn't work it throws an following Exception  "Source Not Found Exception " in the detail of 'source attachment does not contain the source for the file mysqlIO.class'.

```
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Projections;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion;
import com.hibernatehelper.HibernatePlugin;
import com.cir.hibernatebean.CIRMTradeCopiesSlab;

Criteria cr = sesInsert.createCriteria(CIRMTradeCopiesSlab.class);
            //cr.add(Restrictions.eq("mtcsbrncode","MDS"));
            Criterion criterion = Restrictions.eq("mtcsbrncode", "MDS");
            cr.add(criterion);
List AgentRecList=cr.list();
```

Comment: Can you show the entire stack trace? Also, naming a class "mysqlIO" violates Java naming conventions.

Comment: @Olaf  It shows not Exception .It throws an sourec not found Exception of sqlIO.class.It comprises all the relevant declartion method of sqlIO.class

Comment: @Olaf Upto cr.add(criterion); executed and the line of cr.list() not executed .